# How to echo the results from 2 columns within the same table - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to echo out two columns from the same table using php.  What I have below which pulls out all the members first names:

```
<div class="grid-2"> 
    <p><b>MY DETAILS</b></p>
        <?php $query = "SELECT * FROM `tblMember`";

        $result = $conn -> query($query);

        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
          {
            echo $row['fldFName']."<br>";  
          }

        $conn -> close();
        ?>
</div>
```

This does give the first names, but I also want the surnames to be pulled out from the same table, called `fldSName`. Is it a simple AND statement?

Comment: `echo $row['fldFName'] .  $row['fldsName'] . "<br>";`

Comment: ... since you're using `*` (which you shouldn't, but since you are), try `var_dump($row);`

Comment: Basic string handling: concatenate strings using `$str.$str2`. Though PHP doesn't make newlines, so you can do `echo $row['fldFName"]; echo $row['fldFSName"]; echo "<br />";` which is the same as `echo $row['fldFName"].$row['fldFSName"]."<br />";`

Comment: See the manual for string operators; http://php.net/language.operators.string

Comment: @hanshenrik Can I ask what you would suggest as appose to * please just out of curiosity

Comment: Just select the columns you need: `SELECT fldFName, fldSName FROM \`tblMember\``

Comment: Thank you so much @jeroen I guess that is a much better way of doing it rather than loading *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is already in the results since you are using a * in the query.

```
echo $row['fldFName'] . ' ' . $row['fldSName'] . '<br />';
```

Comment: Hi Dave, that doesn't seem to work, error coming back as syntax error. Is the `.' '.` is this mean similar to AND?

Comment: No. `.` joins two strings together, concatenating them. Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: If `fldSName` is a column in the `tblMember` table then that should not cause an error in your loop to display the results of the query. Exactly what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Thank you all, I used your query @Dave but just `echo $row['fldFName']. $row['fldSName']."<br>";` so just one of the full stops and worked fine, so thank you so much :)

Comment: Which is what my answer said. You did NOT need to modify your query at all. The data was already being retrieved.